# Get list of installed applications that can be launched

Tags: android

I have a custom listPreference I would like to display a list of apps that can be launched (contain an activity with CATEGORY_LAUNCHER). The selection will be used later to launch the application. When I did a search for the solution, the list also contained apps that could not be launched. Is there any way to narrow this down?

```
public class AppSelectorPreference extends ListPreference {

@Override
public int findIndexOfValue(String value) {
    return 0;
    //return super.findIndexOfValue(value);
}

public AppSelectorPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> appListInfo = pm.getInstalledPackages(0); 
    CharSequence[] entries = new CharSequence[appListInfo.size()];
    CharSequence[] entryValues = new CharSequence[appListInfo.size()];

    try {
        int i = 0;
        for (PackageInfo p : appListInfo) {
            if (p.applicationInfo.uid > 10000) {
                entries[i] = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                entryValues[i] = p.applicationInfo.packageName.toString();              

                i++;
            }         
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    setEntries(entries);
    setEntryValues(entryValues);
}
```

}

Comment: May be from may answer will help you to get SORT list of Such Application Package Name Which can be  contain an activity with CATEGORY_LAUNCHER and android.intent.action.MAIN .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved:

```
    final Context context = getBaseContext();
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
    CharSequence[] entries = new CharSequence[pkgAppsList.size()];
    CharSequence[] entryValues = new CharSequence[pkgAppsList.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for ( ResolveInfo P : pkgAppsList ) {
        entryValues[i] = (CharSequence) P.getClass().getName();
        entries[i] = P.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager());
        ++i;
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

@Frazerm63 i think you are missing this thing in Your Code

```
  Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN", null);
  localIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
  List localList = localPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(localIntent, 0);
  Collections.sort(localList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(localPackageManager));
```

you have to pass your PackageManager  object in above code .means this localPackageManager

i have not much idea how you can use this in user Code but this will help to get you idea to filter only some category application.

Comment: Looking over that piece of code, this will give me a list. How would I go about changing that into a array for the ListPreference?

Comment: Correction: it shouldn't be converted to an array, but a CharSequence